# Python objects confusion: a=b, modify b and a changes!

Tags: python, variables, reference

I thought i knew Python until tonight. What is the correct way to do something like this? Here's my code:

```
a = ["one", "two", "three"]
b = a  # here I want a complete copy that when b is changed, has absolutely no effect on a
b.append["four"]
print a  # a now has "four" in it
```

Basically i want to know, instead of the `b = a` step, how would I correctly make a copy of a list or dictionary so that when `b` is changed `a` does not change along with it?

Comment: Well, you don't know Python. Or at least you don't know an important part of it, what variables are. See similar question on SO or e.g. http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#other-languages-have-variables.

Comment: @delnan to be fair, it's not an uncommon pitfall to folks who are new to python to understand that variable assignment involving lists assigns references, though the claim "I thought I knew Python" tends to indicate they're not "new" :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

What you are experiencing is the concept of references. All objects in Python have a reference and when you assign one to two names `a` and `b`, this results in both `a` and `b` pointing to the *same* object.

```
>>> a = range(3)
>>> b = a                     # same object
>>> b.append(3)
>>> a, b                      # same contents
([0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3])
```

With lists, you can make create a new list `b` that is a *copy* of another `a` using `b = a[:]`.

```
>>> a = range(3)
>>> b = a[:]                  # make b a new copy of a
>>> b.append(3)
>>> a, b                      # a is left unchanged
([0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2, 3])
```

For a more general solution for any object, use the [copy module](http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html). A shallow copy will copy the references stored within the object you're copying, whereas a deep copy will recursively make new copies of all objects.

```
>>> a = [range(2), range(3)]
>>> b = copy.copy(a)          # shallow copy of a, equivalent to a[:]
>>> b[0] = range(4)
>>> a, b                      # setting an element of b leaves a unchanged
([[0, 1], [0, 1, 2]], [[0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2]])
>>> b[1].append(3)
>>> a, b                      # modifying an element of b modifies the element in a
([[0, 1], [0, 1, 2, 3]], [[0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3]])

>>> a = [range(2), range(3)]
>>> b = copy.deepcopy(a)      # deep recursive copy of a
>>> b[1].append(3)
>>> a, b                      # modifying anything in b leaves a unchanged
([[0, 1], [0, 1, 2]], [[0, 1], [0, 1, 2, 3]])
```

Comment: whats a deep copy and whats a shallow copy. i noticed the dict.copy.__doc__ string says its a "shallow" copy. whats the difference?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/184710/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deep-copy-and-a-shallow-copy

Comment: That's actually a shallow copy, but otherwise the right way to copy a list.

Comment: @Keith Yes, you're right. I was getting to that and now I have. :)

Comment: @james Hopefully the code samples I added help explain.

Comment: thank you so much marcog you helped me understand. especially with the added examples.. shot dude

Answer (score 1):

The correct way of copying an object is

```
 from copy import copy
 a = [1, 2, 3]
 b = copy(a)
```

Pretty simple. There is shortcuts for lists:

```
 a = [1, 2, 3]
 b = a[:]
```

There is also deepcopy() if you want to copy the objects *in* the list as well.

Comment: Be careful of overuse of deepcopy. This can explode your memory usage, and at times gives bizarre errors of "unpicklable object". For nearly all use cases you don't *need* a copy, and for the other cases, a shallow copy will do.

Answer (score 1):

Here are 3 ways to make a copy of list `a`:

Use slice notation:

```
copy_of_a = a[:]
```

Use the list constructor:

```
copy_of_a = list(a)
```

Use the copy module:

```
from copy import copy
copy_of_a = copy(a)
```

These are all shallow copies, which is sufficient for your question. To learn about the difference between shallow copy and deep copy read the [documentation of the copy module](http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html).