# Inserting values into a dictionary without just creating a reference

Tags: python, dictionary

is there a way to insert a dictionary into another dictionary without just creating a reference to the dictionary.e.g

```
dict_a = {}
dict_b = {}
dict_a.insert(key, value)
```

this would prevent the problems that come with

```
dict_a["somekey"] = dict_b
```

Comment: What problems are you trying to address?

Comment: See your last question, `copy` was already mentioned. You went over the same basic problem in 3 questions now, maybe it's time to learn how Python works and how work *with* it?

Comment: actually thc my first question was about variable assignment, my second about copying, and this one, about a different way to insert key and value pairs into a dictionary. id think its fairly different :) either way thanks for your unhelpfull input :)

Comment: @james: Yeah, it's three different questions. But they all go back to the same issue: Python works by reference, not by value. So although the questions are different, the answers are the same.

Comment: You don't. It's always references all the way down (until you get to the turtles ^^). That's how Python works, and we're all getting along just fine with it. Learn how to use it, don't try to avoid it.

Comment: @james: "id think its fairly different".  Take the hint.  They're not actually different.  And **never** complain when people are trying to help you.  It's rude to ask for help, get help and reject that help.  You've been advised how Python works.  Please try to understand the advise instead of rejecting it.

Answer (score 4):

You could use copy.deepcopy on b:

```
>>> a = {'a':[1,2,3]}
>>> b = {'b':[4,5,6]}
>>> a['c'] = copy.deepcopy(b)
>>> a
{'a': [1, 2, 3], 'c': {'b': [4, 5, 6]}}
>>> b
{'b': [4, 5, 6]}
>>> b['b'].append(7)
>>> b
{'b': [4, 5, 6, 7]}
>>> a
{'a': [1, 2, 3], 'c': {'b': [4, 5, 6]}}
```

Using update or copy as above will perform a shallow copy.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

```
 dict_a.update(dict_b)
```

This will insert all the keys/values from `dict_b` into `dict_a` (note: this is in-place and returns `None`)

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a copy:

```
dict_a["dsomekey"] = dict_b.copy()
```

**Edit**: **There is no dictionary method that inserts the value by-value. Python dictionaries always use references.**

Comment: Which is what we just showed him [30 minutes ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588100/python-objects-confusion-a-b-modify-b-and-a-changes). :-/

Comment: For lists :-) I think there may also be a problem with TLDR.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be meaning update?

```
>>> dict_a = {1: 'a'}
>>> dict_b = {2: 'b'}
>>> dict_a.update(dict_b)
>>> dict_a
{1: 'a', 2: 'b'}
```

Or you mean that you want a copy?

```
>>> from copy import copy
>>> dict_a = {1: 'a'}
>>> dict_b = {2: 'b'}
>>> dict_a['dict'] = copy(dict_b)
>>> dict_a
{1: 'a', 'dict': {2: 'b'}}
```

Comment: No. I think he wants to insert the dictionary as a value, and by-value (rather than by-reference).

Comment: Updated while you wrote the comment. :) I realized it when I saw that it was the same guy who asked the other reference vs value questions.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588255/python-dictionary/4588336#4588336) answer is better. You should use `copy.deepcopy` or else you'll get references to objects stored in the dictionary-to-be-copied in the copied dictionary.

Original answer below:

You need to explicitly create a copy of the second dictionary, and set that as the value in the original dictionary.

```
dict_a["somekey"] = dict_b.copy()
```

When you `copy` a dictionary, it does exactly what's on the tin, it creates a brand new copy of the original dictionary.