# array assignment using slicing

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

When I was using array assignment using slicing, there is some thing strange happened. The source code is below:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,2,3,4]).reshape(2,2)
b = np.array([5,6,7,8]).reshape(2,2)
print(id(a))
print(id(b))
b = a[:]
b[1,1] = 10
print(b is a)
print(id(a))
print(id(b))
print(a)
print(b)
```

The result is given as:

[image]

From the result, the *id* of **b** and **a** is different after array assignment, but when I change the value of **b**, the value in **a** also changed. Why is this?

Using Sublime Text, Python 3.4.3.

Comment: That link is about lists.  This question is about `numpy` arrays.

Comment: `a[:]` makes a `view` not a copy.

Comment: @hpaulj Thank you. You are right. Numpy array is different from list.

Comment: I removed the `duplicates` because this is about an array view v copy, not about list copies and deep copies.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list-in-python. **`numpy` arrays are not lists**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With lists, `b=a[:]` makes a copy of `a`.  Changes to `b` will not affect `a` or its values.

But with an `numpy` array, this action makes `view`.  `b` is a new object, but it shares the underlying data buffer.  Changes to values in `b` will affect `a`.

Use `b=b.copy()` is you want a true copy.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/quickstart.html#copies-and-views

Comment: This is the file I found, exactly what you said.[docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/quickstart](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/quickstart.html)

Answer (score 1):

I think you might have an issue with referencing (b=a[:]). Here is a previous answer that might help:

[Python objects confusion: a=b, modify b and a changes!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588100/python-objects-confusion-a-b-modify-b-and-a-changes)