# Why can't I change numpy's array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

My array is from a image whick like below:

```
[[[ 66.17041352  32.64576397  20.96214396]                                                                                                                               
  [ 66.17041352  32.64576397  20.96214396]
  [ 65.96318838  32.36065031  16.13857633]
  ...,
  [ 69.04849876  28.06324166  26.57747623]
  [ 63.7269604   32.96378326  25.94336956]
  [ 53.96807994  39.33219382  23.9025511 ]]

 ...,
 [[ 18.55833403  34.4104455   -9.75497344]
  [ 18.55833403  34.4104455   -9.75497344]
  [ 21.45103128  32.77919479  -3.84284208]
  ...,
  [ 44.64859327  41.89617915  14.25196745]
  [ 43.40291913  43.25109885  17.43372679]
  [ 43.30009306  47.94315449  15.59464532]]

 [[ 18.64249436  31.63054472  -7.56023249]
  [ 18.64249436  31.63054472  -7.56023249]
  [ 23.23099091  32.284216    -3.86411699]
  ...,
  [ 44.98536772  45.0246078   17.92556564]
  [ 45.53417128  45.42120428  17.50264622]
  [ 46.7226915   45.42428651  19.21054283]]]
```

I want to change the array to zero like this:

```
[[[ 0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.]
  ...,
  [ 0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.]]

 ...,

 [[ 0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.]
  ...,

 [[ 0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.]
  ...,
  [ 0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.]]]
```

I know how to make it happen, but I just wonder why my origin code doesn't work.The print shows that nothing changed.

```
for row in image_arr:
    for col in row:
        col = [0,0,0]

print image_arr
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your loop, you are just reassigning the name `col` to the list `[0,0,0]`, over and over and over again. Not at all what you want! To change your 3d array to all zeros, you simply do this.:

```
arr[:, :, :,] = 0
```

Bing bang boom, you're done.

Comment: This is the first answer to make it clear that `col = [0,0,0]` is just a _name rebinding_-- that's the critical problem.  The fact that numpy doesn't return copies here but views of the original object which can be mutated (like `col[:] = 0`) is just a fact about _numpy_; the fact that `col = [0, 0, 0]` was never going to work is a fundamental fact about _Python_.

Comment: Or in fewer characters, `arr[...] = 0` or even `arr[()] = 0`

Answer (score 0):

Is because col is a value not a reference , see [Python objects confusion: a=b, modify b and a changes!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588100/python-objects-confusion-a-b-modify-b-and-a-changes)

try instead :

```
a=0
b=0

for row in image_arr:

    for col in row:
        image_arr[a][b] = [0,0,0]
        a=a+1
    b=b+1

print image_arr
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because `col` is a copy not a reference. This is true for all of python:

CODE Example:

```
simple = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
print simple
for elem in simple:
    elem = 0
print simple
```

OUTPUT:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Try this instead:

```
rows,cols,lens = arr.shape
for r in range(rows):
    for c in range(cols):
        arr[r][c] = [0,0,0]
```

Comment: `col` isn't a copy of anything.  And if it were, then `arr[r]` would also be a copy, and so `arr[r][c] = something` would also fail to modify `arr`.

Answer (score 0):

You change the value col in the loop but it's not related to the original variable image_arr.
You can use `enumerate` to access the index and modify image_arr variable directly. As in the following example:

```
import numpy as np
image_arr = np.arange(30).reshape(3, 5, 2)
print(image_arr)

for i,row in enumerate(image_arr):
    for j,col in enumerate(row):
        image_arr[i][j]=0

print(image_arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are changing `col` to a new list, but `col` is not a reference to a sublist of `row`. Instead, if you change the **elements** of `col`, then you will get the result you want:

```
for row in image_arr:
    for col in row:
        for i in range(len(col))
            col[i] = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

`col` is a 1d array, a `view` of `arr`.  To change its values you need to use slicing notation.  `col=[0,0,0]` reassigns the variable without mutating the iteration variable.  Mutability is a key concept here (and applicable to lists and dictionaries as well).

```
In [254]: arr = np.ones((2,3,4))
In [255]: for row in arr:
     ...:     for col in row:
     ...:         col[:] = 0   # or = [1,2,3,5]
     ...:         
In [256]: arr
Out[256]: 
array([[[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]],

       [[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]]])
```

And since you want to change all the values, `col[:]=0` works just as well as `col[:]=[0,0,0,0]` (in my shape).

But while we are at it, any of these also work

```
In [257]: for row in arr:
     ...:     row[:,:] = 1
     ...:     
In [258]: arr
Out[258]: 
array([[[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
 ...]]])
In [259]: arr[:,:,:]=2     # one : per dimension
In [260]: arr[...] = 3     # ... shorthand for multiple :
```

But why reset `arr`?  Why not make a new array with the same shape (and throw away the 'original')?

```
arr1 = np.zeros_like(arr)
```