# Why do sets seem to behave differently?

Tags: python, set

In the example below, when calling the .add() method on the set B, set A is also affected:

```
A = {0,1,3,4,5}
B = A 
B.add(10)
```

I expect this because A and B are both pointing to the same set object.

However, in this slightly different situation, set A is unaffected:

```
A = {0,1,3,4,5}
B = A
B = B - {0,1}
```

In this second example, why is a new object created for B to point to? What explains this difference in behaviour?

Comment: Differently to what? Every mutable object will show the same behaviour, `B = A` **does not** create a copy. The difference is the kinds of operation - `B.add(10)` mutates the object, whereas `B - {0, 1}` creates a new one.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: The main question here is about the second case, not the first. Your duplicate only explains the first (which the OP already seems to understand). I wouldn't be surprised if this is a duplicate, but it's not a duplicate of [the question you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4588100/364696).

Comment: Then the only real answer is *"because that operation returns a new set, rather than mutating the existing set, [as documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.difference)"*.

Answer (score 1):

You're absolutely correct about the first case - `A` and `B` are the same object.

For the second example, the expression `B - {0,1}` is creating a new set.  That new set is being assigned back to `B`, so now `B` isn't the same as `A` anymore.

Comment: thank you, very helpful

Answer (score 1):

In your first case, yes, `A` and `B` are aliases to the same object, so mutating through one alias is visible on both.

In your second case, `B - {0,1}` is creating a brand new `set` object and `B =`  is *rebinding* the name `B` to it (any time you see `plainname = somethingelse`, it doesn't matter what was bound to `plainname` before; it's now rebound to something new), so it's no longer aliasing the same set as `A`. You could mutate `B` in place, causing `A` to change as well, by doing:

```
B -= {0,1}
```

as `set`s implement a mutating in-place subtract operation which is invoked for `-=` (but not `-`).

Comment: Very clearly explained, thank you